# jQuery form with .load()ed elements ignores them

Tags: jquery

Thanks for reading.

I have a form with a few elements in it.  Inside the form is a `div.graph`.  When the form is submitted, the div is `.load()`'d with the result, which includes some additional form elements, such as a page selector.  The form is then submitted repeatedly with part of it updated each time via the `.load()`.

It's submitted like so:

```
/* ... */
// Build the form info as necessary.
FormAction = './stats_chart.php?cb='+Math.random();
FormDataJSON = $('#frmStats').serializeArray();

// Hide any current report, and blank out the div.
ChartItem.find('.graph').load(FormAction, FormDataJSON, function(){/* etc... */});
```

The results would look like so:

```
/* ... a bunch of crap */
<select id='PageSelector' name='PageSelector'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that if I submit the form, `.load()` some results, and submit it again, the elements that were `.load()`'d aren't present in either the `FormDataJSON`, or the form post.  It seems like they are not recognized by `serializeArray()`.

Any ideas what's going on?  I do have name attribs for all of the elements, the div is inside the form tags, and exploring the DOM with Firebug shows everything where it should be.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I made a workaround by adding a hidden element in the main form and having the select update it before submission, so it is now working, but still would love to know why the elements weren't being seen.

Oddly, if I log it to the console in Firefox, it shows up as it's own root, not attached to the body at all.  Normally, you would see `/html/body/form/div/etc...`, but in this case, it's just `/select`.